# Apache Directory Studio - existing LDAP server

Tags: apacheds, apache-directory

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I hope that it is.  Let me know if I should post it elsewhere..

Several years ago, I wrote a custom partition for Apache DS.  We have an Apache LDAP server running with that partition.  I have not made any changes to `ou=config`: it is a totally separate partition running as it was originally created.

We have been running a simple LDAP server.  We now need to allow access via LDAPS.  In order to do that, it looks like I need to update the configuration in `ou=config`.  So here is my question:  Is it possible to edit the configuration in an existing LDAP server in Directory Studio via the "LDAP Servers" tab (if it is no longer listed there)?  It looks like I can only create a new server there.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new server, create a new connection giving the details of your existing server.  From the connection context menu choose "Open Configuration", then, to activate LDAPS, if you must.  Nowadays your LDAP clients can be configured to Start TLS on port 389, so there's no need for LDAPS in most cases.